# Python: How to access every kth key in an OrderedDict?

Tags: python

I have an OrderedDict (the keys are ordered):

```
od1 = {0:10, 1:3, 2:7, 3:11, 4:30, 5:15, 6:19, 7:4, 8:3}
```

I want a new OrderedDict() object that contains the key:value pairs of every second element of `od1`. That is, I want:

```
od2 = {0:10, 2:7, 4:30, 6:19, 8:3}
```

I have tried:

```
od2 = OrderedDict()
od2 = {k:v for k, v in od1.items() if k % 2 == 0}
```

However, that does not give me an ordered dictionary, and it does not give me all keys. Instead, I get this, which is NOT what I want:

```
{0: 10, 8: 3, 2: 7, 4: 30, 6: 19}
```

How can I get a new OrderedDict() object that contains every kth key and its associated value?

Comment: Your example with `od2` is not how you initialize an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Hmm. It's worked for me in the past. What should it be?

Comment: No with `od2 = {..}`, you actually drop the ordereddict, and use a *vanilla* dict instead.

Comment: @StatsSorceress no, it has should not have worked for you in the past. That is a dictionary comprehension, that creates a `dict` object. It doesn't matter that you did `od2 = OrderedDict()` before, note, you could do `od2 = list()` and it doesn't matter, Python is dynamically typed.

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not give me all keys"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.islice` on the `od.items`:

```
>>> od
OrderedDict([(0, 10), (1, 3), (2, 7), (3, 11), (4, 30), (5, 15), (6, 19), (7, 4), (8, 3)])
```

Then simply:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> OrderedDict(islice(od.items(), None, None, 2))
OrderedDict([(0, 10), (2, 7), (4, 30), (6, 19), (8, 3)])
```

Or, for example, every third key:

```
>>> OrderedDict(islice(od.items(), None, None, 3))
OrderedDict([(0, 10), (3, 11), (6, 19)])
```

`islice` works analogously to list slicing, eg. `my_list[::2]` or `my_list[::3]`, however, it works on any iterable, doesn't support negative step values, and you must use explicit `None` values, but the principles are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting with ordered dict you can just simply use this snippet (Python2.7):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od1 = OrderedDict([(0, 10), (1, 3), (2, 7), (3, 11), (4, 30), (5, 15), (6, 19), (7, 4), (8, 3)])
c = od1.items()[::2]

print OrderedDict(c)  # OrderedDict([(0, 10), (2, 7), (4, 30), (6, 19), (8, 3)])
```

For Python 3.6 it is a slightly different:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od1 = OrderedDict([(0, 10), (1, 3), (2, 7), (3, 11), (4, 30), (5, 15), (6, 19), (7, 4), (8, 3)])
c = list(od1.items())[::2]
print(OrderedDict(c)) # OrderedDict([(0, 10), (2, 7), (4, 30), (6, 19), (8, 3)])
```

Comment: With `od1` as a regular `dict`, this only works coincidentally (before python 3.6, when `OrderedDict` becomes irrelevant): try it with keys of 1000 through 1008. `od1` needs to be an `OrderedDict` as well.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks to be painstakingly pedantic, `OrderedDict` is still relevant in Python 3.6, as `dict` objects maintaining insertion order is merely an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on.... until Python 3.7 makes it officially part of the `dict` spec.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, thank you for the correction; I forgot that detail.

Comment: @ikac - still, with `od1` as a plain dictionary, your code only works by chance.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for eye opening!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
import collections
new_d = collections.OrderedDict([a for i, a in enumerate(od1.items()) if i%2 == 0])
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([(0, 10), (2, 7), (4, 30), (6, 19), (8, 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 od1 = {0:10, 1:3, 2:7, 3:11, 4:30, 5:15, 6:19, 7:4, 8:3}
 od2=sorted([(key,item) for key,item in od1.items() if key%2==0])
 print(od2)
```

output:

```
 [(0, 10), (2, 7), (4, 30), (6, 19), (8, 3)]
```

Answer (score -1):

od2 type is 'dict' that is why you are getting unordered dict.

```
>>> type(od2)
<class 'dict'>
```

quick solutions will be like this:

```
>>> od2 = OrderedDict({k:v for k, v in od.items() if k % 2 == 0})
>>> od2
OrderedDict([(0, 10), (2, 7), (4, 30), (6, 19), (8, 3)])
```

Comment: This will not work. You are passing a `dict` to `OrderedDict`, but **dict objects are unordered**, so the order in the `OrderedDict` will be arbitrary.